# difference between json dictionary and hash

Tags: php, json, hash, dictionary, associative-array

I am developing an application in PHP where in I am supposed to call an external API.
The api specification says

```
Request Type : POST
POST data format : JSON Dictionary or Hash
Mandatory Dictionary / Hash Keys and expected values
1. fname  : value - First name of user
2. lname  : value - Last name of use
...
```

What is the difference between JSON Dictionary and JSON Hash.
How do I implement this in PHP?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A *dictionary* and a *hash* are actually the same thing, by definition they both have key - value pairs.

You can use the `json_decode` function to give you a PHP representation of a dictionary/hash: an **associative array**:

```
$hash = json_decode($some_external_content);
print_r($hash);
```

Likewise, you can convert an associative array to a JSON hash using the `json_encode` function:

```
$json_object = json_encode(array('x' => 'y')); //{'x':'y'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hash and Dictionary are what JSON Objects are called in other languages.

> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.

— http://json.org/

To create one, start with a PHP associative array and run it through [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)